# how to output encrypted text in rsa with conversion from char* to strings

Tags: c++, string, encryption

I need help on how to decrypt the encrypted `strings`. The program does not output the encrypted text.

My code :

```
char* encStr(long long e, long long n)
{
    freopen("C:\\Users\\GBADAMOSI ABDUSSAMAD\\Desktop\\prac.txt", "rb", stdin);
    string line;

    while(getline(cin, line))
        cout<< line <<endl;

    char *str = new char[line.length() + 1];
    char *str1 = new char[2048];
    strcpy(str, line.c_str());

    cout << endl << "\nEncrypting using Public key: " <<endl;

    int i = 0;
    while(i!= strlen(str))
    {
        str1[i] = modExp(str[i], e, n);
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl << str1 <<endl;

    return str1;
}
```

`str1` returns the encrypted string.

```
void decStr(char* str1, long long d, long long n)
{
    char* str2  = new char[2048];   
    cout<< endl << "\nDecrypting using Private key: "<<endl;     
    int i = 0;

    while(i!= strlen(str1))
    {
        str2[i] = modExp(str1[i], d, n);
        i++;
    }

    string str (str2);  
    cout << endl << str << endl;
}
```

The above method does not output the texts encrypted. I need help on this.

Thanks

Comment: C-strings cannot have embedded binary `0`s (unless you always pass the length) and outputting unprintable characters is not going to go well either.  The RSA algorithm will put binary `0`s (and other unprintables) into the output string.  I would normally use `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` for encrypted data and encode as hex before outputting it.

Comment: Do you mean I will decrypt the encrypted data using std:: vector<unsigned char>? Is the hex encoding also to be performed on data before encryting or after?